# NoneType is not iterable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am building an application using Django 2.0 and Python 3, but I am having some issues with parsing a file using a custom class

I have created this class:

```
class MailWareConfiguration:
    _configuration = {}

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._configuration == {}:
            self._configuration = self.dot(data)

    def accessible(self,key):
        if self.exists(key) and (self._configuration[key] and not self._configuration[key] == ''):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def dot(self, data, prepend = ''):
        print('MailwareConfiguration.dot started')
        results = {}
        print('RAW: ' + str(data))
        for key,value in data.items():
            print('RAW VAL: '+str(value))
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                print('KEY: ' + str(key) + ' DICT: '+str(value))
                results = results.update(self.dot(value,prepend+key+'.'))
            else:
                print('KEY: ' + str(key) + ' VALUE: '+str(value))
                results[prepend+key] = value
        print('RAW PROCESSED: ' + str(data))
        print('MailwareConfiguration.dot finished')
        return results

    def exists(self, key):
        if key in self._configuration:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get(self, key, default):
        if self.accessible(key):
            return self._configuration[key]
        else:
            return default
```

The purpose of this class is to process a `dict` into a flat structure `dict` where each subsequent level would be seperated by a dot, similar to what the `config` function does in Laravel PHP.

This is done, so that I can easily provide a readable implementation of a `.json` file outside of `Git`, so that sensitive information such as database credentials are not stored in version control, but still have the values assigned to variables in `settings.py`

My example configuration file looks like this:

```
{
    "debug": true,
    "hosts": [
        "localhost"
    ],
    "database": {
        "name": "mailware",
        "user": "mailware",
        "password": "mailware",
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": "5432",
        "options": {
            "sslmode": "require"
        }
    },
    "language_code": "en-us",
    "time_zone": "UTC",
    "api_only_mode": false,
    "hostconfig": {
        "salearn_bin":"/usr/bin/salearn",
        "sa_bin": "/usr/bin/spamassassin",
        "mailscanner_bin":"/usr/sbin/MailScanner",
        "mailscanner_config_dir": "/etc/MailScanner",
        "mailscanner_share_dir": "/usr/share/MailScanner",
        "mailscanner_lib_dir": "/usr/lib/MailScanner",
        "tmp_dir":"/tmp",
        "sa_rules_dir":"/usr/share/spamassassin",
        "sendmail_bin":"/usr/sbin/sendmail"
    },
    "retention": {
        "records":60,
        "audit":60,
        "quarantine":60
    },
    "mta": "sendmail"
}
```

It all runs fine during `MailWareConfiguration.dot`, but as soon as we are finished processing the `database` property of the `json` data, it crashes with `File /Code/mailware/src/core/helpers.py", line 22, in dot
    results = results.update(self.dot(value,prepend+key+'.'))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` and does not process the rest of the file.

How can I resolve this issue without changing the structure of the file

Comment: `results.update()` mutates itself - it does not return a copy of itself with the changes. So `results = results.update()` assigns `Nonetype` to `results`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reiterating my earlier comment:

You receive the error `NoneType is not iterable` because you assign the output of a void method - `dict.update()` - to the dictionary. The [`dict.update()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) reference states:

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys. Return `None`.

Your code that does this is

```
for key,value in data.items():
    print('RAW VAL: '+str(value))
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        print('KEY: ' + str(key) + ' DICT: '+str(value))
--->    results = results.update(self.dot(value,prepend+key+'.'))
```

The marked line can simply be

```
results.update(self.dot(value, prepend + key + '.'))
```